# Jquery before() and after() used to create a <div> container not inserting closing tags in after()

Tags: jquery, html

I have a 2 containers e.g:

```
<div class="one col-md-6">container one</div>
<div class="two col-md-6">container two</div>
```

And I want to insert  opening tag and  closing tag before and after e.g

```
$( ".one" ).before( "<div class='row'>" );

$( ".two" ).after( "</div>" );
```

But when I inspect, the result is

`<div class="row"></div>`

and not

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="one col-md-6">container one</div>
   <div class="two col-md-6">container two</div>
</div>
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2):

The DOM structure must *always* be valid, at every point in the code. After you call `.before`, the end tag is created *for* you, because otherwise, the structure would not be valid.

Use [`.wrapAll`](https://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) instead:

```js
$(".one, .two").wrapAll("<div class='row'>");

console.log($('.row').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one col-md-6">container one</div>
<div class="two col-md-6">container two</div>
```

Comment: The problem with `.wrapAll`l is that my containers are inside another container in a `foreach` loop. So when I use `.wrapAll` then it wraps the containers I want to add the element in the one main container.

Comment: @Horcrux Can you edit the actual HTML structure in your question?

Comment: @CertainPerformance, I will try, it is long code, using wordpress